# Is it possible to construct a Data Flow Graph DIRECTLY from an AST of a program?

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, taint

I'm trying to perform static taint analysis on multiple programming languages, and was trying to find out if it's possible to construct a Data Flow Graph (DFG) from an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) directly, without having to create a Control Flow Graph (CFG) first.

I found a very interesting project [tree-sitter-graph](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-graph) that I used to construct arbitrary graphs from tree-sitter ASTs.